# Google map integration in flex web application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-maps, flex3

How can i implement google map in Flex web application? Is there any library for implementing google map in flex? I am using Flex3.6 sdk.

Any web link or code would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although deprecated, use the Google Maps for Flash.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/tutorial-flex

Flash and Flex SWC libraries are available.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @Jason. That is what i want. I am working on the same. If i face any issue then ping you again. Thanks